# How to dynamically generate barcode using the jQuery jsBarcode plugin with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, barcode-printing

I found a js barcode generator that works here, my issue is when i try to generate barcodes in loop using the plugin it will not display any thing.. [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Multifunctional-Barcode-Generator-with-jQuery-Html5-Canvas-JsBarcode.html) is the plugin. my code is thus:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../EAN_UPC.js"></script>
<script src="../CODE128.js"></script>
<script src="../JsBarcode.js"></script>

<?
while($Cart = $carting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$pid = $Cart['pid'];
?>
<script>
    $('#barcode<? echo $pid;?>').JsBarcode("546786756445465",{width:1,height:40});
</script>

<? }?>
```

Comment: The code you've got seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ssh5ecqy/. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Well, why should that display anything? You do not appear to have any markup elements the selector `$('#barcode<? echo $pid;?>')` could match...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What you demonstrate is _not_ the code the OP posted...

Comment: I gave the OP the benefit of the doubt and assumed that the missing target element was an oversight in the question, and is actually included in the OPs working code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan are you kidding me? jquery has a plugin for drawing barcodes ???????. with 1 liner code ???????? for the past 2 months I was thinking how I'm going to draw the bar codes in my program . I LOVE JQUERY. thanks for sharing that

Comment: Glad it came in useful for you :) You should really thank JS though, as that's what is generating the barcode image. jQuery is just making it easy to select the element and instantiate the plugin.

Comment: @ arkascha sorry the dynamic  mark up element is there, just that it was omitted in the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to say, the code is supposed to work and I don't know why.

I just added the `document.ready` function to the script and it started working fine.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#barcode<? echo $pid;?>").JsBarcode("<? echo $barcode;?>", width:1,height:40});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<svg class="barcode"
  jsbarcode-format="upc"
  jsbarcode-value="123456789011"
  jsbarcode-textmargin="0"
  jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
<svg class="barcode"
  jsbarcode-format="upc"
  jsbarcode-value="123456789012"
  jsbarcode-textmargin="0"
  jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
<svg class="barcode"
  jsbarcode-format="upc"
  jsbarcode-value="123456789013"
  jsbarcode-textmargin="0"
  jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
```

Script

```
JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
```